# Переменная как имя контроллера

Tags: pdo, php, mvc

Можно ли так? Если нет, то как по другому.

Собственно нужно сделать страницу пользователя, то есть site.ru/id123 где 123 id пользователя.
Как организовать подобный подход, может ли кто показать в примере, или поделится пруфом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала необходимо перенаправить запросы со всех несуществующих файлов на т.н. front-controller, файл, который будет принимать запросы (в 99% случаев это index.php в корне). Это делается на стороне вебсервера и зависит от конкретного сервера.

Затем в дело вступает роутер, который написан на php и является частью приложения - модуль, который примет на вход URI, а в ответ даст идентификатор контроллера, который ответственен за обработку данного URI. URI берется из `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, полученный от роутера ответ разбирает уже приложение. Обычно роутер отдает строку типа `blog/index` или `blog:index`, из которой приложение само достает название контроллера (blog) и действия (index), после чего создает экземпляр контроллера:

```
$request = $router->parse($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // id123 превращается в [route => user/index, params => [id => 123]]
$parts = explode('/', $request['route']);
$controller = new $parts[0];
```

и вызывает соответствующее действие, что-нибудь вроде:

```
call_user_func_array([$controller, $parts[1]], $request['params']);
```

если потребуется совсем подробный разбор - можно заглянуть в исходник Yii, Symfony и прочего :3

Comment: вариант хорош, ну роутинг я произвожу в некой иной форме.
код роутера http://ideone.com/MWxXeA

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно использовать GET и чпу,

Comment: как это реализуется в mvc. нужны примеры

Comment: Создаешься страницу на подобе, site.ru/user.php?act=123 потом в чпу добавляешь замену.

Comment: @bajex мой вопрос был не о процедурном стиле. facepalm

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, директивы .htaccess и процедурный стиль - это разные вещи

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь Apache, то создаёшь или меняешь файл .htaccess и пишешь в нём

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

В скрипте user.php идентификатор пользователя будет виден как $_GET['id']

Тебе нужна будет функция, которая генерирует URL ссылки на пользователя. Ей на вход подаёшь $id пользователя, например `123`, а она возвращает строку `/id123`

```
function getUserUrl($id){
    return '/id'.(int)$id;
}
```

Comment: опять же. я использую паттерн MVC. ну я уже примерно представил себе, роутер с тремя параметрами -> контроллер/метод/ид, потом делаем RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ user/id/$1 [NC,L] и получаем профит id123.
Правильно ли я это представил.